# Adding a class based on a statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery to find a String of text within an element using the following -

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" value="14">
<a id="link-filterattribute-14" class=" jqueryCheck" rel="nofollow" href="/store/filtered/4/12_14/c_7/"> Black </a>
</li>     

<script>
if ($(".jqueryCheck:contains('Black')").length){

}
</script>
```

What I want to do is add a class to the `<input>` If the word "Balck" is found. How do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
$(".jqueryCheck:contains('Black')").prev('input').addClass('yourclass');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".jqueryCheck").each(function(i){
    if($(this).text()=='black'){
        $(this).prev().addClass('someclass');
    }
}
```